# ドメインコントローラの追加について

Tags: windows-server, active-directory

Windows Server 2019を使って1台のドメインコントローラを構築しました。

ルートドメイン名は「hoge.local」、NetBIOS ドメイン名は「HOGE」です。

このドメインにもう1台ドメインコントローラを追加したところ、うまくいったように思うのですが、追加ドメインコントローラのほうのコマンドプロンプトを開くと、

「C:¥Users¥Administrator.HOGE>」みたいな感じで、Administratorの後ろに「.NetBIOS ドメイン名」が付与されています。

これは自然なことなのでしょうか？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

メンバサーバにしてもクライアントにしても、既存のローカルユーザーと同名のドメインユーザーでログインすると通常プロファイルのパスが衝突するので、後者のパスはユーザー名.ドメイン名となります。

ドメイン立ち上げ時だけAdministratorのプロファイルが流用されるのですが、こちらのほうが例外的な動きです。